# JS: How to execute a function 1 that called function 2 from function 2?

Tags: javascript

I'm making an animation system for a canvas game. Every time I want to move a player, I use `entities[0].moveTo(...)`, `entities[0]` is an object, `moveTo()` is its method that executes larger `animate()` function.

```
var moveTo = function(x,y,d){
    if(x!=0) animate(this,'x',this.coords.x+x*tilescale,d,animation_mode);
    if(y!=0) animate(this,'y',this.coords.y+y*tilescale,d,animation_mode);
}
var animate = function(e, prop, val, duration, mode) {
    if(mode){
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        var end = start + duration;
        var current = e["offset"][prop];
        var distance = val - current;
        var step = function() {
            var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
            var progress = Math.min((duration - (end - timestamp)) / duration, 1);
            e["offset"][prop] = current + (distance * progress);
            render();
            if (progress < 1) requestAnimationFrame(step);
            else ## moveTo.onanimationfinished() ##
        };

        return step();
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
};
```

Basically I want a "bumping" animation from two small transforms -- go forward, then go back quick. "go back" part should be shown when "go forward" part is complete. Any way to do this?

Comment: A cleaner approach would be to have only one requestAnimationFrame-loop for the whole game. Each entity then has a state which tells your game's renderer how to display the entity at a given time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new function `bumb` and then call it in the end of `animate`, but you can also give another argument in `animate` function called bumb like this:

```
var animate = function(e, prop, val, duration, mode, bump) {
   if(bump){
      // Bump animatio
   }
   else{
      // Move animation
   }
}
```